# Datepicker doesnt work when loaded by AJAX

Tags: jquery, datepicker

NOTE: I have tried solution which are provided from almost all question but it doesn't work.

So here is my condition now.

I have a div with class `canvasContent` that contain content of page. This `div` sometimes contain `input text` which is binded with `datepicker` like this

```
<script>
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-2:+2",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });

$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({

        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: "-2:+2",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
</script>
```

sometimes it doesn't contain `datepicker` and some point it has to load string which contain `datepicker` using this script.

```
$(".aj").click(function(event) { 
      $('.dimmed').fadeIn(); 
      event.preventDefault();

      $('#datepicker2').removeClass('calendarclass');
      $('#datepicker2').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
      $('#datepicker2').unbind();

      $('#datepicker1').removeClass('calendarclass');
      $('#datepicker1').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
      $('#datepicker1').unbind();

      $('.canvasContent').html('');
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      $('.canvasContent').load($(this).attr('href'),function(){

      $('body').on('focus',"._datepickerrr", function(){
          // $('#ui-datepicker-div').remove();
            $(this).datepicker();
      }
      $('.dimmed').fadeOut(); 
  });
  return false;
});
```

The problem is `datepicker` which loaded to `div` is not work when the `div`s countain `datepicker` previously, but it is work when the current `div`s doesn't contain `datepicker` previously.